# Vim key mapping mismatch

Tags: python, ruby, vim

I code in ruby and python using vim, and my `vimrc` has a setting to enter breakpoints easily:

```
au FileType python  map <silent> <leader>b oimport ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()<esc>
au FileType python  map <silent> <leader>B Oimport ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()<esc>
au FileType ruby    map <silent> <leader>b orequire 'pry'; binding.pry<esc>
au FileType ruby    map <silent> <leader>B Orequire 'pry'; binding.pry<esc>
```

However, occasionally I get the wrong command, e.g. `ipdb` in a ruby file, and I have to restart vim. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you define your mappings globally.

The solution is simple : add the `<buffer>` argument to your mappings in order to make them "buffer-local".

```
au FileType python  map <buffer> <silent> <leader>b oimport ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()<esc>
au FileType python  map <buffer> <silent> <leader>B Oimport ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()<esc>
au FileType ruby    map <buffer> <silent> <leader>b orequire 'pry'; binding.pry<esc>
au FileType ruby    map <buffer> <silent> <leader>B Orequire 'pry'; binding.pry<esc>
```

See `:help <buffer>`.

Also:

- You should use `:nmap` or `:nnoremap` instead of `:map`. Prefer `:nnoremap`.
- You should wrap those lines in autocommand groups and reset them to prevent your autocommands to pile up when you re-source your `vimrc`:

  ```
  augroup python
      autocmd!
      autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <leader>b oimport ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()<esc>
      autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <leader>B Oimport ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()<esc>
  augroup END

  augroup ruby
      autocmd!
      autocmd FileType ruby nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <leader>b orequire 'pry'; binding.pry<esc>
      autocmd FileType ruby nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <leader>B Orequire 'pry'; binding.pry<esc>
  augroup END
  ```

Comment: Thx, s/help <bufer>/help <buffer>/